# WP_List_Table not properly handling returned data?

Tags: wordpress

So following the WPEngineer guide on WP_List_Table (excellent guide by the way), I managed to put together a basic table for the backend of a plugin I'm working on. Using an 'example' array, it works great. Problem I'm running into is that I can't figure out for the life of me how to replace that sample data with actual data! Adding the query where I thought it was supposed to be results in the query variable having the correct data, but the table still returns no contents. The referenced pastebin is what I have so far... any thoughts?

http://pastebin.com/f0DCacfF

**CORRECTION:** It IS pulling the data (if I manually add a row to the database, the table count gets updated), but it's displaying a blank table.

**NOTE:** It seems that the sample data is an array, whereas $wpdb->get_results is returning as a stdClass Object.

**Sample data setup:**

```
var $api_key_list = array(
    array( 'id' => 1,'userid' => 'Quarter Share', 'key' => 'Nathan Lowell', 'desc' => '978-0982514542' )
);
```

**Sample data return:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [userid] => 1 [key] => 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 [desc] => Test API key ) )
```

**Query setup:**

```
$api_key_list_query = "SELECT * from $wpapi_db_table_name";
$this->api_key_list =  $wpdb->get_results($api_key_list_query);
```

**Query return:**

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [userid] => 1 [key] => 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 [desc] => Test API key ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [userid] => 1 [key] => 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 [desc] => Test API key 2 ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following solved my problem.

```
$this->api_key_list = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($api_key_list_return as $obj) {
    foreach($obj as $key => $val) {
        $this->api_key_list[$i][$key] = $val;
    }
    $i++;
}
```